# Slide in Animation on webview data

Tags: android, webview, android-animation, layout-animation

I am showing a description like data which I am showing in webview & 
when uesr click on next I am changing webview data now I want to show some kind of slide in animation while changing webview's data can anyone suggest me how I can set animation to a single webview??

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206511/how-can-i-use-android-transition-effects-in-web-view) post to have the webpage slide in and out. The code is used for a custom webview client.

```
 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
            mProgressDialog.show();
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading " + url);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            animate(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

    private void animate(final WebView view) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks nick I solved it by other way which worked for but thanks for solution I will use it next time..........