# How can I have a smooth transition between pages on Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-animation, transition

I tried to create an Android WebView App but the transition between pages is weird. It shows a fraction of second of a blank white screen before the next page loads.

I then tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206511/how-can-i-use-android-transition-effects-in-web-view) to add a sliding animation effect for page loads. But it is worse, as after the "loading" Dialogue box, there is a fraction of a second of the previous page appearing before loading the next page. That creates a jumpy experience for users.

I just wonder how can I make page navigation on WebView to be smooth. I don't need anything fancy. I just want smoothness. The page transition on the mobile browser (e.g. Chrome) is quite smooth in comparison. It also has a blue progress bar indicating that the page is loading. That is perfect for me. I only need a transition that is comparable to the mobile browser experience.

Thank you very much in advance for all your contributions!

Comment: Have you tested it on multiple devices? Because provided link answer worked fine.

Comment: Ya I tested it on 3 different devices. Sometimes it works fine. Sometimes it doesn't. I think when loading pages that are larger and more complicated, it takes time and it shows a fraction of a second of the previous page before transiting to the next page, so creating a jumpy effect.

Comment: So, I think this issue is related to loading images in web view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use android transition effects in web view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206511/how-can-i-use-android-transition-effects-in-web-view)